# Background color based on condition DATATABLE R

Tags: r, datatables, dt

I want to change the background color of the first and last row of my DATATABLE. The problem is, I only can use styleEqual or styleInterval based on row.number if the argument rownames = TRUE on my datatable function. And i dont want the row names to show on my final output.

Let me try to explain it

heres a example df

```
    df <- data.frame(city = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
                 value = c(0,4,10,15,2),
                 rank = c("5°", "3°", "2°", "1°", "4°")) %>% 
  arrange(desc(value))
```

Im looking for something like this: But with rownames = FALSE. I dont want the extra column with the numbers of row position.

```
DT::datatable(df, rownames = T) %>% 
  formatStyle(0, target = "row", 
              color = styleEqual(c(1,5), "#ecf0f1"),
              backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(1,5), c("#2ecc71", "#e74c3c")))
```

[image]

So, how can i specify the background colors for my last and first row,with rownames = FALSE?

```
DT::datatable(df, rownames = F) %>% 
  formatStyle(0, target = "row", 
              color = styleEqual(c(1,5), "#ecf0f1"),
              backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(1,5), c("#2ecc71", "#e74c3c")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure why it doesn't work with `rownames = F`. You can use `styleRow` to get the result you're looking for.

```
DT::datatable(df, rownames = F) %>% 
  formatStyle(0, target = "row", 
              color = styleRow(c(1,5), "#ecf0f1"),
              backgroundColor = styleRow(c(1,5), c("#2ecc71", "#e74c3c")))
```